# How to add newly created category in hybris powertools category navigation bar?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new at `hybris6.x` development.

I have created a new category with some products in power tools site but now I want to add that category and removing all the remaining categories in the site's category navigation bar.

How to do that? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation bar is a cms component. It uses navigation nodes to display a navigation. Navigation nodes define a tree structure of navigation nodes. Each navigation node can have multiple link components. Link components can point to either a category, a product, a content page or a static URL. As mkysoft already said, there is a perspective in cmscockpit for defining this structure.

Answer (score 2):

Login /cmscockpit and select navigation tab from left top corner. Don't miss synchronization after modification.